# What is equivelant to PHP Zend Framework in Java World

Tags: java, php, zend-framework, jakarta-ee

I have been developing web applications for almost 6 years using the LAMP Stack, and lately I've been using ZEND Framework.

It has a steep learning curve, and it took from me a while untill I figured out its in/outs and the logic behind its MVC Structure.

I've chosen ZF although it is more complex than many other PHP Frameworks because its likely the one which will survive longer.

Currently, I am intending to learn Java J2EE

Trying to invest my previous knowledge with ZEND Framework extensively, so I really need to know what its J2EE framework equivalent

**And Please, I don't wana know about obscure frameworks, or frameworks which no body uses but the gurus,or framweworks created by the insiders to solve problems of their own, or frameworks which are just born to die, or frameworks with no huge developers base, or young cool frameworks which need years to be stable.**

I need to know well known frameworks which are used to create applications for enterprises, which will not gonna die at least for the coming 20 years, hopefully.

I sacrifice simplicity for the sake of stability and career growth..
I intend to learn one framework and just only one, and I will stick to it for life.

**Botton Line: I want to learn the framework which will survive for long, competes aggressively, updated regularly, and which eliminates the need of me learning new framework, and brand new APIs    every single year.**

If possible, I want complete details, and true guidance from experienced programmers who have seen it all and knew it very well.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think Spring library is pretty popular in Java

Comment: "I intend to learn one framework and just only, and I will stick to it for life." -> software development != marriage

Comment: Looking for a framework which will not die for the coming 20 years... is an impossible promise to fulfill. First RC of zend framework was just 4 years ago... who knows where it'll be in another 4.

Answer (score 6):

Hope this link is useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959950/recommend-a-java-framework

Though I don't think there is a zend-framework equivalent for Java, only thing I could think of a good framework is [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) used heavily.

Comment: More specifically, the framework is **[Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

I think [**Tapestry**](http://tapestry.apache.org/) can also be a place to start.